# Androidからクラウドへ通信する際に、アプリ切り替え等によって通信が中断しないようにするには？

Tags: android

こんにちは

Activityで入力した比較的大切なデータをサーバを安全に送信知りたく質問をしました。
Androidからデータを送信すると処理に3～5秒かかり、処理結果をJSONで返してくれるサーバがあります。

このサーバへデータを送信中に、ユーザがアプリが切り替えた場合http通信ってどうなっちゃうんでしょうか？
ActivityでThreadを生成した場合、アプリが非表示になった時にThreadがKillされちゃうことはないのでしょうか

どうやらAndroidにはAsyncTaskやAsyncTaskLoaderというものがあるらしいのですが、どうすれば安全にデータをサーバへ送信出来るののか教えてください。

Answer (score 2):

AsyncTaskは、バックグラウンド処理を実行し、UIスレッドに結果を発揮します：
*　`doInBackground`メソッドは、別のスレッドでデータをサーバを送信します
*　結果は`onPostExecute`メソッドに送られ

かくして、あなたの`Activity`がKillされている場合、`onPostExecute`に入ることはありません:

```
private class DownloadFilesTask extends AsyncTask < URL, Integer, Integer > {

    protected Integer doInBackground(URL...urls) {
        // これは、別のバックグラウンドスレッドで実行されています
        return 0;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Integer result) {
        // これは、UIスレッドで実行されています
    }
}
```

これは、長期タスクためにバックグラウンド`Service`を使用することをお勧めします（[バックグラウンド`Service`リンク](https://developer.android.com/training/run-background-service/create-service.html)）。例えば：

_ IntentService :

```
public class HttpService extends IntentService {

    public HttpService() {
        super("HttpService");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {

        // Intentからデータを取得します
        String params = intent.getStringExtra("fruit");

        // ここでデータを送信します
    }
}
```

_ AndroidManifest :

```
<application
    android:icon="@drawable/icon"
    android:label="@string/app_name">

    .....

    <service
        android:name=".HttpService"
        android:exported="false"/>

<application/>
```

_ Activity :

```
    ...
    Intent mServiceIntent = new Intent(this, HttpService.class);
    mServiceIntent.putExtra("fruit", "apple");
    // Starts the IntentService
    startService(mServiceIntent);
    ...
```

備考 :

`Service`または`AsyncTask`が中断されることはありませんと仮定しないでください。Androidがメモリを必要とする場合、スレッド（`AsyncTask`か`Service`)がKillされてかもしれません。

これに対処するには アプリの状態を保存します。アプリの再起動は、前の状態をチェックします：

```
SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);

boolean shouldSend = preferences.getBoolean("send", false);
if (shouldSend) {
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
    editor.putBoolean("send", true);
    editor.apply();
    // ここでデータを送信します

    .....

    editor.putBoolean("send", false);
    editor.apply();
}
```